# figure overrides linespacing

Tags: floats, line-spacing, setspace

I am using framed package to draw a box around some texts. When I compile it without wrapping it up in the figure command I have no problem. However, when I use it like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{setspace} % for switching between double/single space in document‎
\usepackage{framed}‎‎
\usepackage[top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}‎

\doublespacing‎‎

\begin{document}‎
this is a line

this is a line

\begin{figure}‎
\begin{framed}
this is a line

this is another line
\end{‎framed}‎‎
\caption[figure1]‎{description for figure1}‎‎‎
\label{Fig_1}‎‎ %for Lockstep point!see the comments!  
\end{figure}

\end{document}‎
```

the linespacing reverts to default (see the attached image). Am I missing something?
BTW, I have seen [Post1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4365/how-can-i-stop-latex-from-overriding-instructions-on-spacing) and [Post2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-is-wrong-with-the-line-spacing-of-my-lists-of-figures-and-tables), still no clue. If it is important why I used framed, I must mention that when using double spacing, the text spans more than 1 page and framed does a nice job.

[image]

Comment: Please post a complete but minimal example.

Comment: I have just edited the code.

Comment: The `\label` command should be placed *after* the `\caption` command.

Comment: Why? I don't get the point. What is the difference? But I just edited it and added a comment!

Comment: The `\label` command will refer to the last command that stepped a "referable" counter (e.g., `\section` or `\caption`). To observe this in your code example, add two sections before the figure and `\ref{Fig_1}` after the figure. A `\label` before `\caption` will actually refer to the second section, not to the figure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setspace package patches floating environments, footnotes etc. to be single-spaced. Unfortunately there is no package option to suppress that, so if you don't like your float single-spaced as default, insert the following code immediately after loading of the setspace package:

```
\usepackage[...]{setspace}
\makeatletter
\let\@xfloat=\latex@xfloat % revert setspace patch of floating environments
\makeatother
```

But please note that this will increase the vertical distance between figure body and figure caption, too. (And make the captions double-spaced as well.) If you don't like this, forget about the code above and better use `\doublespacing` inside your `framed` environments.

Comment: I just added the \doublespacing in the first line of code after \begin{framed} and that did the job. Thanks